# When I use a MySqlReader again I get error: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: "Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()"

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to get a data about any account, but I do it again, I get a error, as if the reader is not being created again, but the old one is being used.

```
public static Account getAccount(string login)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(CONNECT_STR_ACCOUNTS))
            {
                connection.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE " + COLUMN_LOGIN + "='" + login + "'";
                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                Account account = null;

                reader.Read(); //Error is hear

                account = new Account(

                                reader[NUM_COL_FIRST_NAME].ToString(),
                                reader[NUM_COL_LAST_NAME].ToString(),
                                reader[NUM_COL_LOGIN].ToString(),
                                reader[NUM_COL_PASSWORD].ToString(),
                                Convert.ToInt32(reader[NUM_COL_LEVEL_ACCSES].ToString()),
                                reader[NUM_COLUMN_BIRHTDAY].ToString()

                );
                
                reader.Close();
                connection.Close();
                return account;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to check the result of `Read()` to see if you have any rows. And you need to remove that **dangerous** SQL injection and use parameters instead. And `reader` and `cmd` need a `using` to dispose them safely. Also why `ToString` an integer only to cast it back again, just cast it straight to `(int)`

Comment: Also, if your query returns more than one row, you need to iterate in a while loop(while reader.Read(){})

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to leverage the using concept I am also kind of confused why you are using a login value in most Database work the information has an announcement integer value here is some example code I use note newData is and integer

```
  public void readUDV()
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{dbName}';Version=3;"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand($"SELECT * FROM FriendsData WHERE FID = " + newData, conn))
            {
                using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        fn = rdr["fxFirstName"].ToString().Trim();
                        ln = rdr["fxLastName"].ToString().Trim();
                        ad = rdr["fxAddress"].ToString().Trim();
                        ct = rdr["fxCity"].ToString().Trim();
                        st = rdr["fxState"].ToString().Trim();
                        zp = rdr["fxZip"].ToString().Trim();
                        ph = rdr["fxCellPhone"].ToString().Trim();
                        em = rdr["fxEmail"].ToString().Trim();
                        rt = rdr["fxInfo"].ToString().Trim();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```